# Cauchy problem wave equation system

Tags: wave-equation, cauchy-problem

I am having the following system of equations

1. $u_{tt}$ - $4u_{xx} = 0 $ where $ x \in R , t>0 $
2. $u(x,0) = 2sin(x) , u_{t}(x,0)=x^2sin(x) ,  x \in R  $

I think it is called Cauchy equation for the wave equation or similar and I tried to find methods how to solve it ,but I didn't find.Can someone explain how such a problem is solved and propose a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the available methods is the Laplace transform. Sumarizing the steps,

$$
s^2U(x,s)-u(x,0)-s u_t(x,0)-4 U_{xx}(x,t) = 0
$$

or

$$
s^2U(x,s)-2\sin x-s x^2\sin x-4 U_{xx}(x,t) = 0
$$

now solving for $x$

$$
U(x,s) = e^{-\frac{s x}{2}} \left(c_1(s) e^{s x}+c_2(s)\right)+\frac{\left(s \left(s^2+4\right)^2 x^2+2 s (s (s
   (s+4)+8)-48)+32\right) \sin (x)+16 s \left(s^2+4\right) x \cos (x)}{\left(s^2+4\right)^3}
$$

Now assuming $c_1(s) = c_2(s) = 0$

$$
U(x,s) = \frac{\left(s \left(s^2+4\right)^2 x^2+2 s (s (s (s+4)+8)-48)+32\right) \sin (x)+16 s
   \left(s^2+4\right) x \cos (x)}{\left(s^2+4\right)^3}
$$

and now anti-transforming we get

$$
u(x,t) = \sin (x) \left(\left(4 t^2+x^2\right) \cos (2 t)+\sin (2 t)\right)+4 t x \sin (2 t) \cos (x)
$$

Comment: Thanks,can you elaborate how did you get on the 3rd row how did U_{xx}(x,t) dissapear?

Comment: Solving the PDE $U_{xx}(x,s)  = \dots $ for $x$

Comment: I am not really sure,how this is done,can you show all the steps?Thanks!

Comment: I will do that ASAP.

Comment: By the way,correct me if I am wrong,but isn't there a general solution based on the coefficient in from of $u_{xx}$ in the first equation , and the value of the 2 functions in the second row of the system?

Comment: The PDE for $U_{xx}(x,s)$ is quite similar to the linear ODE $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}U(x)-(\frac{s}{s})^2U(x)=\frac 12(2+s^2)\sin x$. Now I suppose you can follow...